# R flexdashboard not showing all my data tables in a tabset

Tags: r, datatable, r-markdown, dt, flexdashboard

I have the following code using R and flexdashboard, when I render my page, only df1 is shown, I can see the begening of df2 but it is incomplete.

I can't see the scroll bar for the whole html page neither so I can scroll down to see df2 and df3

Any ideas guys about this problem ?

Thanks !

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
```


### Chart A

```{r}
datatable(df1, filter ='top')
```

```{r}
datatable(df2, filter ='top')
```

```{r}
datatable(df3, filter ='top')
```
````

**EDIT :**

Another solution that resolve my problem is the following layout in a tabset not in a page

[image]

I don't know if this could be done using Flexdashboard so far !

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you need all three datatables in one column, under one header? Or are you able to add multiple headers, e.g., `### Chart A`, `### Chart B`, and `### Chart C`?

Comment: Yes @jordan, I need to put them in a single chart.
The code above is simplified, I have 8 different tabsets and I want to display multiple DT per tabset

Comment: I don't believe you can do that with flexdashboard. flexdashboard currently has layout constraints (unlike Shiny or shinydashboard). You could, however, try a two column format. I'll post an example...

Answer (score 4):

I believe `flexdashboard`'s current constraints will not allow you to display multiple datatables (`DT`) under one header.

Instead, you could consider using a different layout. How about a two column layout?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
```

```{r}
df1 <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = rnorm(100)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  q = rnorm(100),
  p = rnorm(100)
)

df3 <- data.frame(
  r = rnorm(100),
  s = rnorm(100)
)
```

Column {data-width=500}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
datatable(df1, filter ='top')
```

Column {data-width=500}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
datatable(df2, filter ='top')
```

### Chart C

```{r}
datatable(df3, filter ='top')
```
````

**EDIT:**

As requested by OP, you could include each datatable in a tabset, one per tab. Like so:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
```

```{r}
df1 <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = rnorm(100)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  q = rnorm(100),
  p = rnorm(100)
)

df3 <- data.frame(
  r = rnorm(100),
  s = rnorm(100)
)
```

Row {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
datatable(df1, filter ='top')
```

### Chart B

```{r}
datatable(df2, filter ='top')
```

### Chart C

```{r}
datatable(df3, filter ='top')
```
````

For more info on `flexdashboard` layouts, go to RStudio's [website](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/layouts.html).

Comment: I can't try it now, I'll test the code tomorrow by morning.
But is it possible to put this layout in a tabset ? 
The layout won't change ?

Comment: Thank you for your post, actually the first code would be perfect for me if that layout was included in a tabset, is that possible ? 
The EDIT did not work, it gave the same result as the code in my post.